# I am trying to nest Tables while also having relative column spacing

Tags: tables

I am new to creating Docs in Latex. And I am trying to recreate the tables I have shown below. My 2 big problems are:

- I can not get the left column to have an adequate width. Is there a way to make it 30% of the page for example
- I can not get the "nested Table" in row 2 column 3. The Lines I create are way to short.

Here is how i tried to implement the first two rows of the column:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | c | c |}
\hline
Bodenart & Kurzzeichen nach DIN 18196 & Konsistenz / Lagerung & 
\begin{tabular}{c}Steifemodul $E_{s}$ \\ \hline $MN/m^{2}$\end{tabular} \\
\hline
Anorganische bindige Böden mit ausgeprägt plastischen Eigenschaften $(w_{L}>50\%)$ & TA & \begin{tabular}{c}weich \\ \hline steif \\ \hline halbfest\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c}$1-2$ \\ \hline $2-5$ \\ \hline $5-10$\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The magic words you would have needed to know to search for are "column types" and "row span" (since the first two columns span multiple rows - not that the last two columns have nested tables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may liked:

[image]

In table settings are used `makecell` (for multiline column headers and additional vertical spaces in cells), `multirow` for cells which span selected number of rows (actually lines in those rows), and `tabularx` (for table with prescribed width (=`\textwidth`) and automatic determination of `X` column width(s), which enable text braking into more lines):

**Edit:** added changes considering @leandriis comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| L | c | l | c |}
\hline
Bodenart    & \makecell{Kurzzeichen\\ nach\\ DIN \num{18196}} 
                & \makecell{Konsi-\\stenz}
                    & \makecell{Steifemodul\\ 
                                $E_{s}$ (\si{MN\per\metre\squared)}}    \\
    \hline
\multirow{3.6}{=}{%
Anorganische bindige Böden mit ausgeprägt plastischen Eigenschaften $(w_{L}>\SI{50}{\%})$ }
            & \multirow{3.7}{*}{TA} 
                & weich 
                    & 1 -- 2    \\
    \cline{3-4}
            &   & steif
                    & 2 -- 5    \\ 
    \cline{3-4}
            &   &   halbfest
                    & 5 -- 10   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you also want to add `siunitx` for the units in the table header of the last column.

Comment: @leandriis, you are right. Added in answer.

Comment: @Teepeemm, you are right. Corrected now (with some typing/spelling errors together).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Why should I use siunitx instead of just typing the units?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you also like this alternative layout based on `booktabs`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ L  c  l  c }
\toprule
Bodenart
  & \makecell{Kurzzeichen\\ nach\\ DIN \num{18196}} 
    & \makecell{Konsis-\\tenz}
      & \makecell{Steifemodul\\ $E_{s}$ (\si{MN\per\metre\squared)}}    \\
    \midrule
Anorganische bindige Böden mit ausgeprägt plastischen Eigenschaften $(w_{L}>\SI{50}{\%}))$             
  & TA
    & \begin{tabular}{l} weich \\ steif \\ halbfest \end{tabular} 
      & \begin{tabular}{r@{~--~}l}  1 &  2 \\ 2 & 5 \\ 5 & 10 \end{tabular} \\
\addlinespace
     Anorganische bindige Böden mit mittelplastischen Eigenschaften             
  & \makecell{TM,\\ AL}
    & \begin{tabular}{l} weich \\ steif \\ halbfest \end{tabular} 
      & \begin{tabular}{r@{~--~}l}  1 &  2 \\ 2 & 5 \\ 5 & 10 \end{tabular} \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the possibility to use online table generators, for example [Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables#)

Here you can find a WYSIWYG editor for your table and copy and paste the code into your document. For me it works well and the task of creating tables becomes a little bit more time efficient, especially for large tables. You can then fine tune the results to your needs more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\raggedright}p{5cm}clc}[hvlines]
Bodenard & \Block{}{Kurzzeichen\\ nach \\ DIN 18 196} & \Block{}{Konsi-\\stenz} & 
\Block{}{Steifemodul\\ $E_S$ (MN/m$^2$)} \\
\Block{3-1}{}%
\multirow{3}{=}{Anorganishe bindige Böden mit ausgeprägt plastischen Eigenschaften ($w_L>50$ \%)} 
& \Block{3-1}{TA} & weich & 1--2 \\
& & steif & 2--5 \\
& & halbfest & 5--10 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]